# Order by subquery MySQL

Tags: mysql, sorting, mariadb

Hello I want to display the name of the activities according to the order of their addition in the feed (FeedId=incremented id) and with a preselected team number however the order in the subquery is not respected.

MariaDB [database]

```
select name from activity where id=(select ActivityId from feed where TeamId=16 order by FeedId);
```

I tried to take out the order by but without success. Someone would have any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using inner join, something like this

```
select name 
from activity 
inner join feed on feed.ActivityId = activity.id
where TeamId=16 
order by FeedId;
```